# How do I use one object to "contain" another?

Tags: modeling

[image: example image]

Below I've added an image that can hopefully help to make my question clearer.

As you can see, the cylinder which I've used to create this armor model goes through a piece of the armor on the top. Now I could subdivide the cylinder and cut out the portion that I don't need, but I was wondering if there was a quick way to "contain" unwanted sections of an object. In other words, can I delete or make invisible the top portion of my cylinder that's passing through the central collar piece?

Comment: Did you try out the Boolean modifier?

Comment: @Chris I've used the Boolean modifier, but I wasn't able to achieve what I was going for. Is there maybe something I'm missing about it? Also I'm new to Stack Exchange, so i'm hoping the @ tag works.

Comment: Don‘t worry. Whenever you break the rules - the moderators will show their power to you ;) so as long as you don’t hear anything - it is ok. Maybe you show me how you used the Boolean modifier and I will help you with that? You can also quickly create a new blend file with just two rough objects and show me that. I don‘t want to force you to share your blend art - but a blend file is easy to improve. We „see“ all settings and don’t have to guess what the reason could be. You wrote about subdividing - you can also do just one loopcut and cut it off. So you don’t have even just one vertex more